# Port existing android game to unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I already have a game on android. It uses leaderboards, achievements and admob. These features come from google play services.

Now how do I connect these services on android to the game on Unity. I wont be updating the android version right now as it will just be same.

Comment: Please use unity3d tag for such questions.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straight forward to integrate Google play services into your unity application.  There is a plugin you can download and add to your project.  The plugin includes scripts that link in the native c++ libraries for both Android and IOS.

The plug in is on GitHub: https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity